# Asp .net core performance profiling

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Каккие средства можно использовать для профилирования быстродействия веб приложения? Желательно, чтоб можно было более-менее детально расмотреть скорость выполнения и пямять каждой функции без добавления кода.

Comment: Visual Studio Profiler?